# AutoMapper 2.2.1 DynamicMap not mapping underlying type properties (2.2.0 does)

Tags: c#, automapper

I recently upgraded from AutoMapper 2.2.0 to 2.2.1 and a generic method I have stopped mapping properly. Here is a pseudo-version of the method:

```
public void LoadModel<TModel>(int id, TModel model) where TModel : ModelBase
{
    var entity = _repo.LoadById(id);
    _mapper.DynamicMap(entity, model);
    model.AfterMap(); // AfterMap is a virtual method in ModelBase
}
```

`ModelBase` is an abstract class inherited by an instance of a parent class which is passed into this method. In version 2.2.0, corresponding properties from the `entity` instance were properly mapped to the `ModelBase` properties of the `model` instance; after upgrading to version 2.2.1, properties on the `ModelBase` no longer mapped -- no exception thrown, but properties simply are not getting set.

**Update:**
Below is a specific example which demonstrates the difference between 2.2.0 and 2.2.1. In version 2.2.0, the output will be:

```
Male
True
```

In version 2.2.1 the output will be:

```
Male
False
```

The `IsEmployed` property in `Human` does not get mapped in version 2.2.1 but does in version 2.2.0. Here is the example code:

```
namespace TestAutomapper
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tester tester = new Tester();
            tester.Test();
        }
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            var animal = (Animal)new Human();
            LoadModel(animal);
            var human = (Human)animal;
            Console.WriteLine(human.Gender);
            Console.WriteLine(human.IsEmployed.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void LoadModel<TModel>(TModel model) where TModel : Animal
        {
            var tim = new Developer { Gender = "Male", IsEmployed = true, KnownLanguages = 42 };
            AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap(tim, model);
        }
    }

    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public class Human : Animal
    {
        public bool IsEmployed { get; set; }
    }

    public class Developer
    {
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public bool IsEmployed { get; set; }
        public int KnownLanguages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be related to the boxing of `Human` as an `Animal` prior to getting mapped. I am not saying this is a bug, but it is definitely behaving differently between versions.

**Update 2**: The abstract class in my example is a red herring; the example holds true if I use an interface called `IAnimal` instead of an abstract class called `Animal`. The issue seems to clearly indicate that version 2.2.0 considers the *underlying type* when dynamically mapping, whereas, version 2.2.1 does not.

Comment: Could you show a complete code sample highlighting the issue?

Comment: Sure. Let me work that up and I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change related to dynamic mapping between 2.2.0 and 2.2.1.

In 2.2.0 the code looks like this:

```
public void DynamicMap<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
{
    Type modelType = typeof(TSource);
    Type destinationType = (Equals(destination, default(TDestination)) ? typeof(TDestination) : destination.GetType());

    DynamicMap(source, destination, modelType, destinationType);
}
```

and in 2.2.1:

```
public void DynamicMap<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
{
    Type modelType = typeof(TSource);
    Type destinationType = typeof(TDestination);

    DynamicMap(source, destination, modelType, destinationType);
}
```

So effectively it means in 2.2.0 dynamic mapping target type is determined by destination value. If it is null (for reference types) the target is taken from TDestination; otherwise the type of the target object instance determines this.

In AutoMapper 2.2.1 always the type of TDestination takes precedence which is Animal in your case.

Comment: So in my example, `typeof(TDestination)` returns type `Animal`, but `destination.GetType()` returns type `Human`. Makes sense. I assume this change was made to avoid null reference exceptions, but it certainly breaks my code. I guess I will have to leave 2.2.0 in place unless I can update my code with the knowledge that `typeof` will be used and not `.GetType()`. Ugh. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Already found the proper update I need based on this info. Referencing my example code, I simply changed this `AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap(tim, model);` to this `AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap(tim, model, tim.GetType(), model.GetType());`. Thanks for the insight aguyngueran.